# Function call seems to corrupt stack (all parameters)

Tags: c++

I have just introduced compartmentation for a project I am currently working on. For that, I moved a loop out of the main function into its own hpp and cpp file (previously it worked fine).

I created a function that wraps the loop, which takes all of the stack variables the loop previously used directly as parameters. As soon as these vars are passed to the loop function, all of them are corrupted. It looks like all of them are wiped from stack somehow, but I can't really imagine why.

This is the definition of the function:

```
void main_loop_func(char* buffer, const size_t buffer_size, const SOCKET& client_socket, const std::map<std::string, int> option_switch_map,
                const int max_non_block_read_tries);
```

This is how the function is called:

```
main_loop_func(buffer, sizeof(buffer), client_socket, option_switch_map, max_non_block_read_tries);
```

With the vars looking like this when the function call is reached:
[image]

One debugging step later, in the function's cpp file, at the function header, the vars suddenly look like this:
[image]

I have no clue as to how I could debug this / find out where the problem lies. Help is very appreciated! I would provide more information/code, but I really don't know which part of my code might be responsible for this behaviour.

Comment: you pass an invalid pointer (variable `buffer`) to your function. how you create `buffer` before passing it to `your main_loop_func` ? can you post more code please ?

Comment: Try to go on more step, then it should be displayed correctly. I don't know why, maybe Visual Studio does not load the correct stackframe when the debugger stops at the signature of the function, but does so in the first line of the function.

Comment: churill you were right. It was indeed just displayed wrong, and the reason my program crashed was something else. I incorrectly assumed the wrong values shown by the debugger were the issue and therefore didn't check the next frame